# "Did you have..." or "Have you had..."

Tags: word-order, questions, sentence-choice

I know that this question was asked before and I read the other posts but I'm still which one to use. I was just talking with a friend and I asked, "Have you had a tiring day?"... I thought I was right because I read somewhere that I should use "Have you had" when addressing something recently done, but then I googled the two sentences and "did you have" got a lot more of entries.

Ps. I asked that question 'cause she said, "Half of my body is sleeping".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with questions of verbal aspect generally, in many contexts both are perfectly good. "Have you had a tiring day" is regarding the day as continuing into the present - it might actually not have finished yet, or the tiring part may be over. "Did you have a tiring day" does imply that the day (or at least, the tiring part of it) is over.

There is also a question of variety of English: I believe we are somewhat more likely to use the perfect in this sort of case in British English than they are in American.

Comment: Which one is the perfect? Have you had?

Comment: Yes. "Perfect" in English grammar refers to a verb construction consisting of a part of _have_ followed by a past participle: